# Javascript - [Why?] Assigning a variable to an object

Tags: javascript, variables, object, variable-assignment

Why is it that when I assign a variable to an object and make a change to that variable it also changed the objects? For example:

```
c = 26;
a = b = c;
a += 1;

a      // 27
b      // 26
c      // 26
```

but

```
z = {};
x = y = z;
x.ab = 5; 

x      // Object {ab: 5}
y      // Object {ab: 5}
z      // Object {ab: 5}
```

Why (in the example above) does `y.ab` and `z.ab` exist? I only modified `x` not `y` or `z`. Howcome in the first example (with the integers), when I changed the value of `a`,  `b` and `c` weren't affected?

Comment: Mutability is the keyword here.

Comment: Not a JS expert, but the Java explanaition would be that you are dealing not with objects but with references to the object, so `x` `y` and `z` all point to the only object that has been actually created

Comment: Short answer: because a,b and c refer to an immutable scalar value, and x, y and z refer to a mutable object.

Comment: possible duplicate of... so... many... questions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign an object to a variable, it just makes a reference to the original object, it doesn't make a copy. So all the variables refer to the same object.