# JavaScript array assign issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I just created two arrays and assigned a inserted a key value pair to one of the array. Then i assigned or copy an array to other. After that i added another key value pair to second array, but it reflects to the original array also. For example.

```
var array1 =[];
var array2 =[];
array1.value1 ='1';
array2 = array1;
array2.value2 ='2';
console.log(array1); // it prints {value1:1, value2:2}
```

why its changing the array1 object while i added a key value pair for array2?

Comment: Well obviously you're not making a copy. And you're not using an Array properly.

Comment: Duplicate question of many others asked before.  I will go find one of those dups.

Comment: @jfriend00: While the answer to the referenced question also answers this question, I do not think of this question as a duplicate of that one.  Not that I doubt that this is likely a duplicate of **something**.

Comment: Here's one that deals with the expectation that an object assignment makes a copy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586423/javascript-why-assigning-a-variable-to-an-object

Comment: @squint - And your reference is actually marked as a dup of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language.  There are many, many to choose from.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yeah, I know. I just wanted to provide one that was specifically trying to make a copy via assignment. Doesn't matter. Like you said, there are many.

Answer (score 1):

When you do something like `array2 = array1;` you are just setting `array2` as a reference to `array1`. To make a copy of array1 you need to do `array2 = array1.slice();`

Furthermore, you can not set [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) elements with `array1.value1 ='1';`. What you have done there is convert your array to an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). So what you really should be doing is:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
array1[0] = 1;
array2 = array1.slice();
array2[1] = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing `array2 = array1;` you are assigning the array1 object to array2 variable. So modifying array2 will modify the object associated i.e. array1

Answer (score 0):

Because you pass by reference `array1` to `array2`. You need to do a copy like:

```
array2 = new Array(array1);
```

Comment: This actually does not work. It creates an array with array1 as an item in the array.

Comment: I don't know.  I countered it, though.  :-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet: So did I. Two people now upvoted it.