# Not Understanding Basic JavaScript Execution Flow

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-assignment

My basic understanding is that JavaScript runs from top to bottom, returning to functions when they are called, but then proceeding to the next line of code after calling a function.

That makes sense when I look at this code as an example:

```
var a = 5;
var b = a;
a = 2;
console.log(b);
// My expected output 5, works as expected
```

I get lost when I look at this though:

```
var a = [5];
var b = a;
a.push(2);
console.log(b);
// My expected output [5], instead returns [5,2]
```

If I assigned the var b the value of a when it was 5, why does the value of b change to [5,2] when 2 wasn't pushed to a until the NEXT line?

I'm obviously missing some basic fundamentals here.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value

Comment: Objects (and arrays are objects in JavaScript) are passed by reference-- so you're not pointing`b`  to the value of `a` at that time, you're pointing `b` to the array that `a` is referencing, so any mutation to that array will be visible to all variables pointing to that object/array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array assign issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745170/javascript-array-assign-issue)

Comment: Variable `a` and `b` are pointing to the same value in memory, so every change on `a` will modify `b`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you see `[5, 2]` is because:

- `b` is a reference to `a`
- so when you edit `a`, `b` will reflect those changes as `b` points to `a`

In a nutshell, complex objects (i.e., arrays and objects) in `JavaScript` are passed by reference, whereas primitives by value:

- this has primarily performance benefits. For instance, think of having a large object---every time you pass that object you would end up making copies of it, which is probably not a good idea
- fortunately, there are ways of performing deep object cloning. Here is a resource on this: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)
- a thing to keep in mind: only when there are no more active references to an object, the chunk of memory allocated to that object gets reclaimed during the garbage collection (i.e., check [What is JavaScript garbage collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864516/what-is-javascript-garbage-collection))

Here is a good discussion related to your question: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing 2 onto the array and since b points to a, the output from console.log(b) outputs [5,2] instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` still contain the same array.

The issue is that `a.push(2);` does not assign a new value to `a`; instead it modifies the actual array stored in `a`. Because `b` contains the same array, any modification to it is visible through both `a` and `b`.

This issue does not arise with so-called "primitive" types like numbers because numbers have no mutable structure. You cannot modify `2` to suddenly be `5011`, but you can modify an array to have a different size and different contents.