# whats the difference between the following ways of assigning an array to variable and when to use each?

Tags: javascript, typescript

1st way:

```js
number= [{},{}];
numberCopy= number;
```

2nd way :

```js
number= [{},{}];
numberCopy= [...number];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a shallow copy and a deep copy with JavaScript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512712/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shallow-copy-and-a-deep-copy-with-javascript-ar)

Comment: @mplungjan This question is not a duplicate of the one you set. OP is asking a question about pointer assignment and a shallow copy, not the difference between a deep and a shallow copy

Comment: the code would not work anyway. the dupe explains all there is to know about assignment deep copy and shallow copy. There is not much else to be learned from this question - I can add more dupes if you are not happy

Comment: @mplungjan I agree that this question is a duplicate. However, as it seems OP is not used to StackOverflow, I think choosing a question closer to OP's is more appropriate, like this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745170/javascript-array-assign-issue

Comment: So we add it to the list

Comment: @Seblor Member of SO for 6 years