# prototypical inheritance in javascript ,cloning property

Tags: javascript

how can I achieve below things in javascript

```
var parent = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6
}

var child = parent;
console.log(child.b); // 6

//now if I change the value of b
parent.b = 7

console.log(parent.b); //7
console.log(child.b); //7
```

//but I want to preserve the previous value of the object property it should not change now.it should show 6 instead of 7 in case of console.log(child.b)

https://codebunk.com/b/696347863/

Comment: There is no inheritance going on here. You're looking to clone the object.

Comment: Your code has nothing to do with inheritance or prototypes.

Comment: **Important:** you're maintaining two references which point to the same value in memory.  So, every change in any of those two references will modify the value in memory.

Comment: `var child = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parent));`

Comment: @Lain - That's an **extremely** poor way to duplicate an object. It fails in lots of ways and makes a completely unnecessary pass through *text*.

Comment: The fundamental thing here is that there is no parent/child or inheritance relationship here at all. As @Ele pointed out, `var child = parent;` makes both the `child` variable and the `parent` variable point to the **same** object. So naturally any change you make to that object will be visible whether you look at that (one) object through your `child` or `parent` variable. **If** your goal with `var child = parent;` was to create a copy, see the linked question's answers. If your goal was to create some kind of inheritance relationship, you wouldn't do it that way...

Comment: ...you'd use `var child = Object.create(parent);` instead, which creates a new object that uses `parent` as its prototype. More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create But if you do that and change `parent.b`, since `child` doesn't have its own `b`, you'll still get `7` for `child.b` (since `b` is inherited).

Comment: @CertainPerformance the dupe question only explains how to clone rather than explaining what to do for solving the real problem.

Comment: @Ele - Based on what the OP says they want (assigning to `parent.b` not to affect the value of `child.b`), cloning the object rather than just referring to it is the real problem. The OP's mention of inheritance and such is, I think, a red herring. (Not sure I fully agree with the closure, but I don't *disagree* enough to unclose it myself, esp. in light of the `parent.b`/`child.b` thing. :-) )

Comment: @Ele - I do think your comment (and mine afterward) are critical to helping the OP understand *why* they need to make a copy. (E.g., because `child = parent` doesn't. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, but the OP has a lack of knowledge on what is really happening when s/he only assigns an object to a variable.

Comment: @Ele - Yes, wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255297/why-does-this-function-mutate-data That's an array, but arrays are objects in JavaScript.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586423/javascript-why-assigning-a-variable-to-an-object

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840293/setting-a-variable-equal-to-another-variable

Comment: @T.J.Crowder then what is the solution

Comment: @Ele - Looks great to me.

Comment: @user3647491 - As far as I can tell, the solution to your question is: Make a copy of the object. See the answers to the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/).

Answer (score 0):

When you do `var child = parent` both child and parent refer to the same object instance in memory. If you want to copy the property of parent to the child you need to create a new object with the same keys as the parent object.
You can use spread `...` or [object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for this

```js
var parent = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6
}

var child = {...parent};
var child1 = Object.assign({}, parent);

console.log(child.b); // 6
console.log(child1.b); // 6

//now if I change the value of b
parent.b = 7

console.log(parent.b); //7
console.log(child.b); //6
console.log(child1.b); //6
```

> For deep cloning, we need to use other alternatives because `Object.assign()` and `...` copies property values. If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies that reference value.

Comment: This is not a totally cloning approach, this is just spreading the first level of the object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have removed that line. I was not talking in those terms. Although yes it sounds confusing if you think it like that.

Comment: var child = {...parent};                                                                                                               SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...  at createScript (vm.js:56:10)                                               
    at Object.runInNewContext (vm.js:93:10)

Comment: @user3647491 The editor is giving you this error, It Might be the case that editor doesn't support ES6 syntaxes although it is completely a valid syntax. You can use `Object.assign()` instead of `...` if it helps.